# How to read wrongly formatted string in csv properly

Tags: python, string, csv

In csv, for a column there is ambiguity in string. Because of that, I'm getting `6` values in list instead of `5` values as output.

**Code:**

```
import csv
csv_data = csv.reader(file('test.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
    print row
```

I tried to replace `"` with `space` to get atleast as normal string with out any quotes, as shown below,

```
for row in csv_data:
    print [r.replace('"',' ') for r in row] # This did't worked as expected.
```

**Input:**

row in csv file looks like this,

```
1,2,"text1", "Sample text ""present" in csv, as this",5

"Sample text "present" in csv, as this" # Error due to this value.
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '2', 'text1', 'Sample text present" in csv', 'as this', 5]
```

**Expected output:**

```
['1', '2', 'text1', 'Sample text "present" in csv, as this', 5]
```

Comment: Why not use `pandas.read_csv` with bad_lines argument.

Comment: @Vishnudev As already, I'm using `csv.reader` in complete development. I prefer not to use other libraries. There is no solution in `csv.reader`?

Comment: @Vishnudev Can you share solution with pandas?

Comment: Could you provide the data?

Comment: @Vishnudev Already provided in question. Use the same single line data. *Note:* I don't want to ignore that row.

Comment: There is no "proper" way to read a wrongly formatted file. Your case is really bad as the data field contains *both* delimiters (`,`) and quotation marks (`"`). A heuristic fix would be "double every quotation mark that is not at the beginning or the end of a line, or adjacent to a delimiter (ignoring whitespaces)", but even that is not foolproof...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost embarrassingly hacky, but seems to work at least on the sample input shown in your question. It works by post-processing each row read by the `csvreader` and tries to detect when they have been read incorrectly due to the bad formatting — and then corrects it.

```
import csv

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        for row in csv.reader(file, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar=None):
            newrow = []
            use_a = True
            for a, b in zip(row, row[1:]):
                # Detect bad formatting.
                if (a.startswith('"') and not a.endswith('"')
                        and not b.startswith('"') and b.endswith('"')):
                    # Join misread field backs together.
                    newrow.append(', '.join((a,b)))
                    use_a = False
                else:
                    if use_a:
                        newrow.append(a)
                    else:
                        newrow.append(b)
                        use_a = True
            yield [field.replace('""', '"').strip('"') for field in newrow]

for row in read_csv('fmt_test2.csv'):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', 'text1', 'Sample text "present" in csv, as this', '5']
```

Comment: Getting same issue even after using `with`.

Comment: Using `with` is not the only difference — but as I said I can't reproduce the problem with this code on my system.

Comment: Means, you are getting a list of `five` elements after using `1,2,"text1", "Sample text "present" in csv, as this",5` as a row in `csv`?

Comment: No, I'm getting 6 elements both both before and after — sorry, misunderstood your question.

Comment: shaik: Try revised answer.

Comment: Can you tell about performance of these function? Because the csv files have `millions` of records. If possible, add time complexity of this function. Thanks.

Comment: And it's not working when there is unbalanced quotes in row. like `1,2,"text1", "Sample text ""present" in csv, as this",5`. Can you please update for that? remove all `"` and replace with empty space.